# How to tell if I'm on Debian stable or unstable?

Tags: debian

I'm currently running Debian 9.0 (stretch) which I upgraded from jessie. I upgraded long time ago and don't remember if I did a stable upgrade or I went to unstable instead. I want to move to stretch stable but I can't figure out how to check if I'm on stable.

also if I happen to be on stretch unstable is it possible to move to stable stretch?

Comment: How about `cat /etc/os-releases`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `lsb_release -a`

```
guiverc@755-deb:~$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
Release:    testing
Codename:   buster
```

You'll note my debian is a 'testing' release, and thus not stable.  Debian 9 (stretch) is the current stable release of debian.

> The current stable distribution of Debian is version 9, codenamed
>   stretch. It was initially released as version 9 on June 17th, 2017 and
>   its latest update, version 9.8, was released on February 16th, 2019.
>   https://www.debian.org/releases/

On another box I get

```
guiverc@de2900:~$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie
```

The 8.11 shows it's a stable release (could also be called an *old-stable*).

Comment: Mine just says || Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release: 9.0
Codename: stretch
|| does that mean its stable?

Comment: I don't have a debian 9 box running/up, but I'd expect your box to respond 9.8 as it's the latest 9 being released on 16-Feb-2019 (https://www.debian.org/).  Have you `sudo apt dist-upgrade` ('upgrade' doesn't allow all upgrades to occur having restrictions requiring 'dist-upgrade' or 'full-upgrade').  Your answer replied a number release, so it is a stable release (just an outdated stretch as I see it).

Comment: yes it's outdated I haven't updated it in awhile. I wanted to upgrade but I didn't remember if was on unstable or not so I didn't want to risk an upgrade if I was on unstable. thanks!